# Any open neighborhood of a boundary point contains an interior point and an exterior point.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subseteq X$ be a subspace, show that any open neighborhood of a boundary point of $A$ contains an interior point and an exterior point

The definition I'm working with for boundary point in this case is that $p \in X$ is a boundary point of $A$ if it is not an interior point and it is not an exterior point.

*What I tried so far* Let $p \in X$ be a boundary point of $A$. By definition $p$ is not an interior point nor is it an exterior point of $A$.

Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ in $X$ then by definition of $U$ being open we have $B(p, r) \subseteq U$ for some $r > 0$.

Suppose $B(p, r)$ contained no interior points of $A$. Then every $y \in B(p, r)$ has the property that for all $\delta > 0$ we have $B(y, \delta) \not\subseteq A$.

Hence for all $\delta > 0$, there exists a $z_{\delta} \in B(y, \delta)$ such that $z_{\delta} \not\in A$.

---

That was where I got stuck, what I was trying to do was argue by contradiction that $B(p, r)$ contained no interior points of $A$ and showing that we arrived at a contradiction and then arguing by contradiction that $B(p, r)$ contained no exterior points of $A$ and showing that we arrived at a contradiction, but I'm not sure how to do it by contradiction.

How could I go about proving this theorem?

Comment: What are the precise definitions you are using? Is an intetior point just the usual topological definition and an exterior point an interior point of the complement of A? I guess not, for you could take A to be a line in the euclidean plane and the claim would fail, right?

Comment: @Pedro I'm not using the topological definition. The definition of interior point I'm using is that $x$ is an interior point of $A$ if $A$ contains some open neighbourhood of $x$ and $y$ is an exterior point of $A$ if $X \setminus A$ contains some open neighborhood of $y$

Comment: But that is precisely the topological definition right? So the claim would be false in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. If $\mathring A=\emptyset$ , that is, if $A$ has not interior points, then how can a neighborhood of a point of the boundary of $A$ contain an interior point of $A$? This happens, for instance, if $A=\{a\}$, where $a$ is a non-isolated point of $X$.